# Autofac: Resolving Embedded Resource?

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, autofac, embedded-resource

Is it possible to resolve an embedded resource via AutoFac?

I'm not sure if it is possible.

EDIT

I am wondering whether AutoFac can be used to resolve Views that are embedded into a DLL within an MVC Application.

Comment: What sort of embedded resource? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks for your comment, I have edited the question to include specifically what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: And the View is what? A class? A template? A text file?

Comment: @MarkSeemann It is a view written in the razor syntax - it could be defined as a text file.

Comment: So, the answer provided by Peter Lillevold pretty much tells you what you need to know. Since DI Containers only resolve instances from types, it doesn't make much sense to try to resolve a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autofac is used to resolve *instances* from *types*. If an embedded resource can be represented as a type, sure you can register that type in your container.

Comment: Your answer is as vaque as the question. +1 for that :-)

Comment: @Steven - thank you :) then I consider it mission accomplished :)

Comment: Answer not so vague when put into context! Thanks to Peter and Mark, I had a suspicion that this was the case, but I thought I would ask.

Comment: @Matt - great stuff. As they say, there are no stupid questions :)